# Google Maps - отображается только логотип Google

Tags: android, google-maps

Всем привет, возникла странная проблема. Гуглокарты не показываются, видно лишь логотип Google в углу. Что не так?

Манифест:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.test.****" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

```
<resources>
        <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">***</string>
    </resources>
```

Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Разметка

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

В гуглоконсоли указан пакет (пекейж) и SHA-1 отпечаток. Пробовал и debug и release сборку - ничего не меняется. Самой карты нет

Comment: а google_maps_key указан верный ключ? <br> Часто проблема что ключ не верный. Или не указан. <br> Тогда сама карта не отображается

Comment: @tosh, получить ключ > выбрал проект > enable api > скопипастил ключ (другой был) > безрезультатно

Comment: запускаете на реальном устройстве?

Comment: @Andriy, да, Google Play сервисы установлены, сами карты тоже

Comment: можно получить доступ к вашему ПК через теамвивер? напишите данные на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych, я с телефона работаю

Comment: не совсем понял ваш ответ. уточните что вы имеете в виду

Comment: @Andriy Martsinkevych, у меня нет компьютера, я создаю приложения на андроиде. приложение AIDE.